# Custom 404 error page not being rendered by css

Tags: php, css, xampp

I'm new to PHP, i created a website with a custom 404 error page which i added to my **.htaccess file.** in **XAMPP**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /dir/another-dir/404.php
```

It works when i enter an invalid link but my css code isn't rendering the page, it just comes up as pure HTML without any styling.

I also tried renaming the file with a **.html** extension. But i still get the same result.

Still, when i run the page on its own the css works just fine.

How can i solve this please?

Comment: Did you check if link rel="stylesheet" is pointing to the right path to locate the css...you could also copy your style to head section of the html within that php file

Comment: Yes the rel is set.

Comment: So you're saying i should keep all my styling in the php file, yes?

Comment: That works 100% of the time since well you don't have to deal with absolute paths otherwise your css could not be working because in your rel you just did not specify the right path

Comment: Okay thanks, that fixed it. But now my background image is not loading ‍♂️‍♂️

Comment: Again because of the wrong path...because your bg url() in the css is pointing to the wrong direction...why don't you just check your paths and fix them... you'll run into many problems

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot